# ElasticSearch aggregation with nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I'm trying to migrate a statistic application from pure MySQL to MySQL + ElasticSearch v6 and I cannot find how to do correctly my aggregation.
Because an example is better than smocky explanations, here are extracts of my data:

The mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "sample_type": {
            "properties": {
                "hash": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "zone": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "labo_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "raw_results": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "result": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "code": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The index content:

```
{
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "faf3294351e84ab0bb08becf2025a0f6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "hash": "hash1",
                "labo_id": 1,
                "zone": "22",
                "raw_results": [
                    {
                        "result": "S",
                        "code": "AMX"
                    },
                    {
                        "result": "S",
                        "code": "AMC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "faf3294351e84ab0bb08becf2025a0f6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "hash": "hash2",
                "labo_id": 1,
                "zone": "22",
                "raw_results": [
                    {
                        "result": "R",
                        "code": "AMX"
                    },
                    {
                        "result": "S",
                        "code": "AMC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "faf3294351e84ab0bb08becf2025a0f6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "hash": "hash3",
                "labo_id": 1,
                "zone": "56",
                "raw_results": [
                    {
                        "result": "S",
                        "code": "AMX"
                    },
                    {
                        "result": "R",
                        "code": "AMC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "faf3294351e84ab0bb08becf2025a0f6",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "hash": "hash4",
                "labo_id": 1,
                "zone": "56",
                "raw_results": [
                    {
                        "result": "S",
                        "code": "AMX"
                    },
                    {
                        "result": "R",
                        "code": "AMC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And the result I try to achieve:

```
code  |  result | zone |  count
---------------------------------
AMX   |  R      | 22   |   1
AMX   |  S      | 22   |   1
AMX   |  R      | 56   |   0
AMX   |  S      | 56   |   2
      |         |      |
AMC   |  R      | 22   |   0
AMC   |  S      | 22   |   2
AMC   |  R      | 56   |   2
AMC   |  S      | 56   |   0
```

I'm trying to count the result values for each code, grouped by zone. What could be the right way to retrieve this result?

*Do not hesitate to tell me if I could use a better index structure.*

Thank you,
JM

**EDIT 2018-04-02**

I found a query that could do the job:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "zone": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "zone"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "raw_results": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "raw_results"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "code": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "raw_results.code"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "result": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "raw_results.result"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could parse this result to obtain my array of results but I will continue to search for a query giving the aggregation in the right order.